# WooCommerce JQuery Conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

The following jQuery works fine on any of my basic template pages:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });

});
```

However this does not seem to work on my WooCommerce single product page. It is supposed to allow the user to click through tabbed content using the following HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Product Description</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Product Specification</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Delivery</li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>
```

I'm assuming this is some kind of conflict with WooCommerce's jQuery, but I'm unsure of how to resolve this issue. Here's a link to a single product with the tabbed content: http://sg09.co.uk/product/a-product/. Any help would be much appreciated :]

Comment: You can refer to the jQuery.noConflict() method here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: in your general.js add $ = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: @MukeshPanchal I've tried the jQuery.noConflict method, with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: can you plz add general.js in footer after wp_footer() and see it work

Comment: I have tried the said code and it works... problem is you have error on you console...

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add below code in first line of this file /wp-content/themes/lemon-fencing/js/general.js and see if it works:

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: @Leon Burman also can you plz add "slick" library file so it not give errors

Comment: I agree with @Mukesh Panchal, because doing this, you can also use also the shorthand `$` instead of `jQuery` in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab');
        jQuery('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        jQuery('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        jQuery(this).addClass('current');
        jQuery("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });

});
```

Comment: I've tried the above and using the no conflict method, none of which seem to make any difference. I'm really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Many plugin authors and theme developers are aware of this, and they use 'jQuery' instead of '$' to be safe.

```
/* Normal jQuery you see everywhere */
$("#ele").jquerymethod();

/* "Safe" jQuery you see in WordPress */
jQuery("#ele").jquerymethod();
```

In your case you can also use jquery in this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {      
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
       var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
       $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
       $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
       $(this).addClass('current');
       $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });     
});
```